# alinear imagenes verticalmente html

Tags: html, css

Cual sería la forma correcta de alinear estas dos imagenes?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<img src= "resources/menu.png" id="button-menu" width= "40px" height= "40px" style="margin-top: 5px"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<img src= "resources/logo.png" id="logo-menu" width="200" height="57" style="margin-top: 5px"/ >
```

He intentado marcarles el mismo margen arriba, entre otras cosas, pero solo me marca de más no de menos, no tengo muchos conocimientos de css. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alinear dos o más objetos del DOM puedes utilizar [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), en tu caso podrías alinear ambos al centro de la siguiente forma:

```
#button-menu, #logo-menu {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Las opciones de alineación que tienes son las siguientes:

> baseline | sub | super | text-top | text-bottom | middle | top | bottom

Espero sea de ayuda saludos ;)

Comment: Gracias, lo había intentado juraría y no me resultaba, pero ahora si. ;)